# Google Chrome <video> issue

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am trying to use a the html5 video tag. It works fine on safari and firefox, but on chrome the screen flashes and goes blank. But if I resize the browser window the video shows up again. I have put the code on a test page and also included below.

http://www.bilalallawala.com/test.html

Any help would be appreciated

```
<video poster="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bilalallawala/resources/video/cover.jpg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" style="background-size:cover;width:100%;height:auto;position:fixed;left:0;">

    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bilalallawala/resources/video/tl16x9.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bilalallawala/resources/video/tl16x9.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Comment: Works for my Chrome, except the FPS is really low on this old PC.

Comment: I am trying it on a mac with chrome Version 24.0.1312.45 beta
If i scroll my mouse the video appears but if i load the page and dont click or press anything the screen is blank

Comment: The video works perfectly on my Chrome! and I don't see any problem with the code either!

Comment: which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: i am seeing the problem in chrome 25.0.1364.172 on my macbook pro.

Answer (score 1):

I did a couple quick tests and it looks like the problem goes away if you remove the `poster` attribute. This should still work out for you, since the browser will display the first video frame as soon as it is available, and the first frame is the same as the poster you were using.

I have no idea *why* this was happening, though.

A couple other notes:

- `autoplay` is a boolean attribute, so it should either be `autoplay` on its own, or `autoplay="autoplay"`, not `autoplay="true"`
- these videos are *really* big files to make a user download. You may want to consider trying to shrink them down.